# How to render multiple buttons by iterating over an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner with React creating a chatbot that returns a set of button choices for every action. I'm using Socket.io on the server end and React on the front.

I want every button to have an OnClick function which I'm unable to implement

**Here's my data format that server returns**

```html
var data = {
    buttonShow: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'I DID NAAAAHT'
        },
        {
            text: 'OH HAI MARK'
        }
],
    message: {
        author: "Mark",
        time: '12:00 PM',
        message: "Did you hit Lisa?"
    }
};
```

**Here is my Chat Window component class**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import io from "socket.io-client";

class ChatWindow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            message: '',
            time: '',
            buttonShow: false,
            buttons: [],
            messages: [],
            buttonSelection: ''
        }
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:8080')

        this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', function(data){
            addMessage(data);
        });

        const addMessage = data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data.message]});
            this.setState({buttonShow: data.buttonShow});
            this.setState({buttons: data.buttons});
            console.log(this.state);
            //if(this.state.buttonShow==false){}
        };

         this.sendButtonSelection = e => {
            this.setState({buttonSelection: e.target.value});
            console.log(e.target.value);
        };
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    {this.state.messages.map(message => {
                        return(
                            <ul className="chat">
                                <li className="">
                                    <div className="chat-body clearfix">
                                        <div className="header">
                                            <strong className="primary-font">{message.author}</strong> <small className="pull-right text-muted">
                                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>{message.time}</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>{message.message}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    {<ChatInput myDataProp = {this.state.buttonShow} myButtonProp = {this.state.buttons} onClickProp = {this.sendButtonSelection}/>}
                    {}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class ChatInput extends React.Component {
    render(){
        if(this.props.myDataProp == false) {
            return (
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input id="btn-input" type="text" className="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                        Send</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.myButtonProp.map(function(item, i){
                        return(
                        <Button buttonProp = {item.text} buttonOnClick = {this.props.onClickProp}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

class Button extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-round" value={this.props.buttonProp} onClick={this.props.buttonOnClick}>{this.props.buttonProp}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = ChatWindow;
```

However, when this component is rendered, I see this error -

**Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

This is killing me. I've tried everything possible.

Comment: on which line is the error ?

Comment: @jbcazaux turns out the error was here - {this.props.myButtonProp.map(function(item, i){
                        return(
                        <Button buttonProp = {item.text} buttonOnClick = {this.props.onClickProp}/>
                        )
                    })}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass `thisArg` to `map` [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
>     // Return element for new_array
> }[, thisArg])
> ```

```
{this.props.myButtonProp.map(function(item, i){
                        return(
                        <Button buttonProp = {item.text} buttonOnClick = {this.props.onClickProp}/>
                        )
                    }, this)}
```

Or use arrow function instead.

```
{this.props.myButtonProp.map((item, i) => (
  <Button buttonProp = {item.text} buttonOnClick = {this.props.onClickProp}/>)
)}
```

Comment: Sweet! This worked. Thanks a lot Yury. 'This' bindings get very confusing. I'm still not sure how this worked. But thanks for helping out.